# How to Delete MSSQL Table Rows if they are Older than One Year

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, time, sql-delete

I am trying to create a PHP query to delete SQL table rows if the CURDATE column is a year old.

For example, if the current date is 2014/04/1 and the SQL table row's curdate column's data is 2013/04/1 than that table row will be deleted.

For a code example, I am looking for something like:

```
$sql = "DELETE * from Orders WHERE Curdate == 'CURDATE - 365 days'";
$query = mssql_query($sql);
```

From my knowledge the above code wouldn't work as it is not correct syntax, but is there something with working syntax that is similar to that?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE * from Orders WHERE Curdate == DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: @Michael: I won't recommend that, my friend. Give me an up vote only if I deserve it. And you will get up votes for your answers too. When you look back after getting 10k or 20k of reputation (I am sure you can because I have checked the quality of your Q&As), you will be much more satisfied if those reputations are **hard earned**. Make your own way through SO, my friend.

Comment: @Michael: My suggestions: Edit new Q&As (gives +2 reputation until you reach 2k), provide good answers for questions in your knowledge. Ask more questions. And you can be proud when you see your own reputation.